# Tile textures misaligned after rotation of vertices

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm facing a problem that uv-textured tiles in my world do not fit together correctly when a rotation is applied to the tiles.
I'm writing a city builder game with tiles forming a chunk mesh like in a voxel based system (verts, tris and uvs).

The following screenshots shows road tiles where the rotated tile textures do not fit to the other tiles.
If no rotation is applied to a tile it looks correct. So how I calculate the rotation must be wrong.

[image: vertical road has 0 rotation and horizontal road has 90 deg rotation]

[image]

This is my tileset atlas:

[image]

I tested it with a rotated version of a tile which was rotated in the tileset image already. No misalignment in this case because no vertice rotation was needed. So i'm pretty sure there is something wrong with my rotation method.

This is how I construct the mesh and how I rotate the tiles with `RotateVerticesAroundPivot()`:

```
private void AddTileDataToChunk(Vector2Int pos, int type = 1, int textureIndex = 0, float angleDegrees = 180f, float height = 0f) {
        Vector3[] tileVerts = world.tileGeometries[type].vertices.Clone() as Vector3[];
        Triangle[] tileTris = world.tileGeometries[type].triangles;

        if(angleDegrees != 0f) {
            Vector3 center = CalculateVerticesCenter(tileVerts);
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angleDegrees, 0);
            RotateVerticesAroundPivot(tileVerts, center, rotation);
        }

        int baseVertexIndex = vertices.Count;

        // Calculate offset for position
        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(pos.x, height, pos.y);

        // Add vertices with offset
        for (int i = 0; i < tileVerts.Length; i++) {
            vertices.Add(tileVerts[i] + offset);
        }

        // Add triangles
        for (int i = 0; i < tileTris.Length; i++) {
            triangles.Add(baseVertexIndex + tileTris[i].a);
            triangles.Add(baseVertexIndex + tileTris[i].b);
            triangles.Add(baseVertexIndex + tileTris[i].c);
        }

        // Add UVs by texture index
        Vector2[] tileUvs = new Vector2[4];
        int row = textureIndex / world.textureHeightInTiles;
        int col = textureIndex % world.textureWidthInTiles;
        Debug.Log(textureIndex + " -> in row " + row + " and col " + col);
        tileUvs[0] = new Vector2((float)(col + 1) / world.textureWidthInTiles - world.textureUVOffset, (float)(row + 1) / world.textureHeightInTiles - world.textureUVOffset);
        tileUvs[1] = new Vector2((float)col / world.textureWidthInTiles + world.textureUVOffset, (float)(row + 1) / world.textureHeightInTiles - world.textureUVOffset);
        tileUvs[2] = new Vector2((float)col / world.textureWidthInTiles + world.textureUVOffset, (float)row / world.textureHeightInTiles + world.textureUVOffset);
        tileUvs[3] = new Vector2((float)(col + 1) / world.textureWidthInTiles - world.textureUVOffset, (float)row / world.textureHeightInTiles + world.textureUVOffset);
        uvs.AddRange(tileUvs);
    }

    private Vector3 CalculateVerticesCenter(Vector3[] verticesArray) {
        Vector3 min = verticesArray[0];
        Vector3 max = verticesArray[0];

        // Find the minimum and maximum points in each axis
        for (int i = 1; i < verticesArray.Length; i++) {
            min = Vector3.Min(min, verticesArray[i]);
            max = Vector3.Max(max, verticesArray[i]);
        }

        // Calculate the center point using the minimum and maximum bounds
        return (min + max) * 0.5f;
    }

    private void RotateVerticesAroundPivot(Vector3[] verticesArray, Vector3 pivot, Quaternion rotation) {
        for (int i = 0; i < verticesArray.Length; i++) {
            // Translate the vertex to be centered around the pivot
            Vector3 centeredVertex = verticesArray[i] - pivot;

            // Rotate the centered vertex
            verticesArray[i] = rotation * centeredVertex + pivot;
        }
    }
```

I hope someone can help me out :-)

Thanks!
Frey